# executing N times in bach an emacs macro

Tags: emacs, macros, batch-processing

I have an Emacs macro(named/saved)  in  a mymacro.el file

I would like to  execute N times the  macro  in batch mode
like this:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/mymacro.el   test.txt -f MyFoo
```

Question how to add N times in the lisp mymacro.el code ? 
  :-)

Answer (score 0):

ErgoEmacs has a [good page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_command_line_argv.html) on this. What you want to do is reference the `argv` variable after calling emacs with the `--script` option. `(elt argv 0)` will give you the value of the first argument you specify. `(elt argv 1)` will give you the second argument, etc.

For example, let's say you call the following command:

```
emacs --script ~/mymacro.el ~/test.txt 22
```

- Emacs will call the script `~/mymacro.el`.
- `(elt argv 0)` will give you `"~/test.txt"`.
- `(elt argv 1)` will give you `"22"`.
- `(elt argv 3)` will give you `nil`.

You can also use the variable `command-line-args`, outlined [here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html)

To specifically batch-execute a macro a number of times, borrowing from [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsScripts#toc3) on the wiki, we can create a script to run mymacro on a file, in the file `run-mymacro.el`:

```el
;; Insert the macro here with `insert-kbd-macro`
(fset 'mymacro [...])

(defun : ()
  (let ((file-name (elt argv 0))
        (repeats (string-to-int (elt argv 1))))
    (find-file file-name)
    (condition-case nil
        (execute-kbd-macro (symbol-function 'mymacro) repeats)
      (error nil) )
    (save-buffer) )
```

We can then call this script as so:

```
emacs --script ~/run-mymacro.el ~/test.txt 22
```

This will open the file `~/text.txt`, run your macro 22 times and save the result. The original file should be saved in a backup with `~` at the end of the filename.

This is all untested, so it may need some tweaking before it works 100%.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack for your helpful answer. on the way to test it :-)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, is it the case that you want to run the command `emacs --batch -l ~/mymacro.el test.txt -f MyFoo` N times?

If so, and if you are using Linux, it is easier to just use the for-loop of Linux shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..N}  # replace N by your wanted number
do
   emacs --batch -l ~/mymacro.el test.txt -f MyFoo
done
```

Comment: hello thanx but not possible; in fact  each  text line is changed by the macro, then the macro go next line . so executing through  1 shell would always restart first line.  iwould like this :

Comment: from the emacs buffer line  :     ESC 10 my-macro...... # Execute 10 times the named/saved macro  my-macro ( lisp code in mymacro.el)